# animation for alpha transition in background of view not working

Tags: java, android, xml, android-animation

I want the background color of my TextView to transition from one alpha value to another (same color, only alpha changes) and then back to the first, indefinitely. I'm trying with the following code:

```
ValueAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(myTextView, "backgroundColor", R.color.textBackOpaque, R.color.textBackTransparent);
        animator.setDuration(2000);
        animator.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());
        animator.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
        animator.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
        animator.start();
```

and defined both colors in colors.xml like this:

```
<color name="textBackOpaque">#690bace1</color>
<color name="textBackTransparent">#3b0bace1</color>
```

The thing is, instead of animating, it just paints the background of my TextView with an awkward color (looks like it's overlaying both colors at the same time or something like that, it doesn't move or transition at all). I couldn't find where the problem is, I don't know how to debug such a procedure and google searches didn't help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Solved it, I was passing to function `ofInt` the IDs of the colors defined in the xml instead of their hex representation. I replaced `R.color.textBackTransparent` with `0x3b0bace1` and `R.color.textBackOpaque` with `0x690bace1` and the animation worked as expected.